# If Date is mostly deprecated and we're to use Calendar, what is the equivalent of DateFormat class?

Tags: java, date, date-format

I'm new to this Java thing and I'm a little unclear on how I would write my own DateFormat subclass if Date is (mostly?) deprecated.

1. Should I be using Date or Calendar?
2. If Calendar across the board, what class replaces DateFormat?

Comment: `DateFormat` has not been deprecated, just `Date`

Comment: I would suggest that you do not mutate `Date`s. You could build a wrapper around Date if you needed to enforce that. For some projects that would be overkill.

Comment: Ideally, you ought to use JODA time instead of anything built into the JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `java.text.DateFormat class` is **not deprecated**, you use `java.util.Date` class as a **bridge** to format a `java.util.Calendar` object using `java.text.DateFormat` class.

```
java.text.DateFormat---> use this class to format dates.
java.util.Calendar  ---> use this class to perform date related operations.
```

Comment: Thanks.  What do I use to **store** dates then?  Immutable dates.  Just Date?

Comment: hmm, not really, java.util.Date's instance actually represents a mutable date and time .

Comment: Well I'm not going to pass around milliseconds, particularly if I need to format a lot.  So I guess I'm stuck with it?

Comment: `Well I'm not going to pass around milliseconds` i dint really get what you meant by that, but as i said, you usually use dateformat to format java.util.Date in certain format.

Comment: I mean, if DateFormat takes in Date, and I have to format dates a lot, then I have to use the Date class, despite it being mutable.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Date` represents a specific millisecond in time. In other words, `Date` is a wrapper around a long millisecond value. `Calendar` is used for getting the specific day of the week, month, etc. of a `Date`.
2. Use `DateFormat`. You can use the `getDate` method of a `Calendar` to pass a `Date` object to `DateFormat`.

Also, you may find Joda time useful.